# Simple Android Grid Layout

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do something relatively simple but really struggling.
I want to do something like this:

[image]

Explanation:

I want to create a block of fixed height (say 100dp) that is separated into three cells (that are separated by the green dashed lines shown in the picture above). The cells should also be of fixed size

The text in each block would be updated at runtime, and I want an arbitrary number of these blocks

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you add some code of what you have tried already.

Comment: You have to use custom listview for this kind of Layout@ Jason Green

Comment: Post your xml code what you have tried so far for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a cardview embedded in a recyclerview. then you can set the number of such blocks in run time.
If you wanted to fix the number of blocks, then you can use Relative Layout.

Sample Relative Layout can be :

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/largetxt1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="TEXT"/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/smalltxt1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:text="MORE SMALLER TEXT"
android:layout_below="largetxt1"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:text="CLICK"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/largetxt1"
adnroid:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
/>
.
.
.
.
..

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the sample for the first set of boxes. You can set use the same and repeat it for the number of sets you wanted. Make sure to place layout of views correctly

Comment: I would try this, thanks. Since i'm brand new to android development, I would like some explanation if you don't mind. What I was thinking of doing, is figuring out the number of blocks I want, and than having a for-loop that creates this number of objects, where every object contains the layout and content I described above. Is it now how it's done in android?

Comment: If you want to populate your view with for-loop, you should definitely use a card view and recyclerview. But, as you are saying, you are new to android, I would suggest, you manually create the number of blocks in layout.xml file and use it. If you want to do it your way, find quick videos on youtube about recycler view and card view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use weightSum and layout_weight attribute xml file

Comment: `weightSum` is **optional** and serves little or no purpose. `layout_weight` is what you need. But it only works in a LinearLayout and its derivates.